# MySQL - Making MAX /group by run faster

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

assuming I have the following table

```
+------------+--------+--------+
|    date    | Seller | Amount |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2017-03-01 | Anne   |  10.00 |
| 2017-03-01 | Pete   |  18.00 |
| 2017-03-03 | Dan    |  20.00 |
| 2017-03-03 | Dex    |   3.00 |
| 2017-03-07 | Pete   |     11 |
| 2017-03-07 | Anne   |   3.00 |
| 2017-03-08 | Pete   |  12.00 |
| 2017-03-08 | Dex    |   1.00 |
| 2017-03-09 | Dan    |  21.00 |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

my goal is to find the last transaction of a person. my query for this is

```
SELECT date, Seller, MAX(date)
FROM transaction
WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-31' 
ORDER BY Seller;

+------------+--------+--------+
|    date    | Seller | Amount |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2017-03-07 | Anne   |   3.00 |
| 2017-03-08 | Pete   |  12.00 |
| 2017-03-08 | Dex    |   1.00 |
| 2017-03-09 | Dan    |  21.00 |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

unfortunately, with 5 million rows it needs at-least 9 minutes to complete. Any work around to make this faster?

Comment: It's just depend on your hardware and software... Even though you got the best query.. it's all just depend on the capabilities of the machine and software you using.

Comment: I don't know your server's specs, but 9 minutes sounds pretty slow for 5m rows. Is your table's date column indexed? That might help.

Comment: so this is the best query? this is  noted, Report date is indexed, no improvement.